# Java read Oracle EXP command output

Tags: java, oracle, command, streamreader

I need to run the Oracle EXP command through a Java program and print somewhere the command output.

The EXP command is correct, the dump file is created correctly when I execute my Java code, but I'm experiencing some issues to get the output.

This is an snippet very similar to the one I'm using to read the output:

```
String line;
String output = "";
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommand);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        output += (line + '\n');
    }
    input.close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(output);
```

As I said, the command is correctly executed (verified through the generated dump file), but nothing appears on my console and my Java programs doesn't terminate either.

The same code works perfectly if I use another command, as "ls -l" instead of "exp ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name said, it might be that the error stream buffer is full and thus is blocking the programm execution.

Either try to start a `Thread` to also read the error stream or use the `ProcessBuilder` class to redirect the error stream to stdout (which you already read).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe exp is writing to standard *error* output rather than standard output.

Try to use `p.getErrorStream()` instead of `getInputStream()`